# Get all values from biggest group

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table of students and a table of books that they borrowed. I need to find a student who borrowed the most books and show titles of these books.

Currently I have a list of students and number of books that each student borrowed, sorted descending. I can get the student who borrowed the most by using `Top 1`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Students.Name, Students.LastName, Count(Books.Title) AS BorrowedBooksCount
FROM (Meldunek INNER JOIN Students ON Meldunek.pesel = Students.pesel) 
INNER JOIN Books
ON Students.pesel = Books.pesel
GROUP BY Students.Name, Students.LastName
ORDER BY Count(Books.Title) DESC;
```

How to show names of books of a student who borrowed the most books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the student who borrowed the most books:

```
select top 1 m.pesel
from Meldunek as m
group by m.pesel
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can use this in a `where` clause for filtering.  But you should take into account that multiple students might have the same value.  So, use `in` rather than `=`:

```
where s.pesel in (select top 1 m.pesel
                  from Meldunek as m
                  group by m.pesel
                  order by count(*) desc
                 );
```

This logic can be inserted into your query, so you return only the top borrowing students.

The complete query looks like:

```
select s.Name, s.LastName, b.Title
from (Meldunek as m inner join
      Students s
      on m.pesel = s.pesel
     ) inner join
     Books as b
     on s.pesel = b.pesel
where s.pesel in (select top 1 m2.pesel
                  from Meldunek as m2
                  group by m2.pesel
                  order by count(*) desc
                 );
```

Comment: But I want to show titles of all the books the student borrowed. Currently when I select title it only selects one title, but the student borrowed many titles.

Comment: I'm a beginner in SQL, so it took me a while to understand what I was doing wrong, because the query in my question is different than my real query, but I finally understand it. Thank you.